RuntimeError: Model class modules.firebase-push-notifications.models.Notification doesn't declare an explicit app_label
error
RuntimeError: Model class modules.firebase-push-notifications.models.Notification doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

for some reason i do not get this error when i try run manage.py runserver but if i use vscode debugger, this error shows up
the debugger was working fine, this error popped up randomly
setting.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.sites"
]
LOCAL_APPS = [
    'home',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'chat.apps.ChatConfig',
    'admin_panel.apps.AdminPanelConfig',
]


Why do you have LOCAL_APPS as a separate list? Why not include your  local apps in INSTALLED_APPS
